# The program needs to stop when the user enter 209,312,414

Tags: c#

I need the program to stop when the user enter 209, 312, 414. My while loop is not working  because the program continue. I made different other way but at the end the loop continue it does not stop when I enter 209, 312, 414. I will take any other suggestion.

```
using System;

        public class program
        {
            public static void Main()
            {
                const double PRICE209 = 12.99, PRICE312 = 16.77, PRICE414 = 109.07;

                double price;
                int stockNum;

                Console.Write("Please enter stock number. ");
                stockNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

                while ((stockNum == 209) || (stockNum == 312) || (stockNum == 414))
                {
                    if ((stockNum == 209) || (stockNum == 312) || (stockNum == 414))
                    {
                        if (stockNum == 209)
                        {
                            price = PRICE209;
                            Console.WriteLine("The price for item # {0} is {1}", stockNum, price.ToString("C"));
                        }
                        else if (stockNum == 312)
                        {
                            price = PRICE312;
                            Console.WriteLine("The price for item # {0} is {1}", stockNum, price.ToString("C"));
                        }
                        else if (stockNum == 414)
                        {
                            price = PRICE414;
                            Console.WriteLine("The price for item # {0} is {1}", stockNum, price.ToString("C"));
                        } // end of the else if statement
                    } // end the if statement 
                    Console.Write("Please enter stock number. ");
                    stockNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
                }  // end the while loop
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.WriteLine("press <enter> to terminate program");
                        Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
```

Comment: put a `break;` inside each `if` statement

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. The program you show here will exit the loop once the user enters any number other than `209`, `312`, or `414`. If the user enters something that's not a number, the program will just stop with an exception. If you mean you want the loop to exit once the user has entered three different numbers having the values `209`, `312`, and `414`, then you just need to keep track of which ones have been entered (e.g. in `bool` variables) and include that information in your loop condition. What is the _specific_ question here? What are you having trouble with?

Comment: Have you head or CASE statement? :)

Comment: According to MSDN - The while statement executes a statement or a block of statements until a specified expression evaluates to false. The way to use it is `while(true)`. So, what you did in your code is actually looping whenever you receive `209`, `312` and `414`. Also, I don't see why there's `if-else` for `209`, `312` and `414` when you plan to stop if these numbers are the input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your while loop to:

```
while ((stockNum != 209) && (stockNum != 312) && (stockNum != 414))
```